# How do I bind a UISegmentedControl to a ViewModel command?

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

New to Xamarin and mvvmcross and I'm trying to bind a UISegmentedControl's ValueChanged event to a command in the ViewModel.

The viewModel command looks like this:

```
    public ICommand DonorCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _donorCommand ?? (_donorCommand = new MvxCommand<string>(m =>
            {
                DonorIndividual.SetVisible(m);
                DonorBusiness.SetVisible(m);
                OnPropertyChanged(() => CurrentDonor);
            }));

        }
    }
```

My binding looks like this:

```
        this.CreateBinding(DonorType).For(c => c.ValueChanged).To((DonationViewModel vm) => vm.DonorCommand).Apply();
```

I get an error when I try to compile saying: `Cannot convert 'lambda expression' to non-delegate type 'string' (CS1660)`

So I tried to make a new command in the ViewModel of type int instead of string (after-all who looks at the text of a multi-part control for what to do?):

```
    private ICommand _donorTypeCommand;
    public ICommand DonorTypeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _donorCommand ?? (_donorCommand = new MvxCommand<int>(m =>
                {
                    // break here to see what's happening
                    OnPropertyChanged(() => CurrentDonor);
                }));

        }
    }
```

With this as the binding:

```
        this.CreateBinding(DonorType).For(c => c.ValueChanged).To((DonationViewModel vm) => vm.DonorTypeCommand).Apply();
```

I get the same error. (verified it complains about type 'string' in each case) Not sure what that mean How can I do this binding?

Answer (score 1):

it's because it is trying to infer your command type (`<string>`) to `ValueChanged`, which is not a string property.

so, you may want to have a look at this :

http://fetchmytip.blogspot.be/2015/02/ios-uisegmentedcontrol-custom-binding.html

the trick is to create a default target binding for all `UISegmentedControls` that will automatically bind to the value of `UISegmentedControl.SelectedSegment` when it changes, in your case, your command will have to be of type `<int>` then (like .SelectedSegment)